# Ostream operator strangley not accepting my Stack pointer

Tags: c++, oop, overloading, operator-keyword

The code for the overloaded ostream operator

```
template<class T>
ostream& operator<< (ostream& streamer,Stack<T>& stack)
{
    if(stack.isEmpty())
    {
            streamer << "[]";
    }
    else
    {
            Stack<T> tStack = stack;

            streamer << "[";

            while(tStack.top!=NULL)
            {
                    streamer << tStack.top->element;

                    tStack.top = tStack.top -> next;

                    if(tStack.top)
                            streamer << ",";


            }

            streamer << "]";

    }
    return streamer;
```

}

The error is quite long here is the link....
http://pastebin.com/qt4WTEiV

I also tested the function like this....

```
Stack<int> *s1 = new Stack<int>();
cout << "Pushing...." << endl;
s1->push(1);
s1->push(2);
s1->push(3);
s1->push(4);
s1->push(5);

cout<< *s1 << endl;
```

friend function...

```
friend ostream& operator<< <T>(ostream&,Stack<T>&);
```

SOLVED: never i had ~Stack() somewhere in my code

Comment: it is very strengleyyyyyy

Comment: Show us a little bit more of the error please.

Comment: Show the full error mesaage. It seems that the problem is related to the copy constructor.

Comment: Post `Stack` declaration. How `tStack.top->element` operator `<<` is implemented? Are you sure that `element` is of type `T` and not a kind of wrapper?

Comment: It is a template class? I guess you can call it a wrapper.

Comment: The error says you're dereferencing `streamer` (as in `*streamer`) but that's not what your code here shows us.

Comment: I have tried to take the dereference away then it prints an memory address

Comment: so please don't show that you return streamer in your code! show real code and resulting errors

Comment: Well what is `tStack.top->element`? That's probably the address that's being printed.

Comment: its is a integer being returend

Comment: Can you post more code please (namely the declaration of `operator>>` and a bit more of the `Stack` class).

Comment: The friend declaration should not have the template argument: `friend ostream& operator<< (ostream&,Stack<T>&);`

Comment: I get another error if I omit the <T>

Comment: @oomjos I think I know what it is, but just post it anyway please.

Comment: pitrus's answer shows you what it should be.

Comment: http://pastebin.com/ZPTuiaZQ

Comment: @oomjos don't forget about template<class T>, see answer

Comment: I did. I somehow doesn't work well in a .h file

Answer (score 3):

the error you posted

> Stack.C:37:10: error: no match for ‘operator*’ (operand type is
>   ‘std::ostream {aka std::basic_ostream}’)    return *streamer;

tells that you are dereferencing `ostream`, which is not correct. Change this to return a reference to the `ostream`:

```
return streamer;
```

and also be sure that other output operations used in `ostream& operator<< (ostream& streamer,Stack<T>& stack)` like

```
streamer << tStack.top->element;
tStack.top = tStack.top -> next;
```

are well defined. 
Lastly, declaration of

```
friend ostream& operator<< <T>(ostream&,Stack<T>&);
```

should be changed into:

```
template<class T>
friend ostream& operator<< (ostream&,Stack<T>&);
```

Comment: please show a complete code then, with friend declaration, and the errors. Always show actual code and resulting errors

Comment: be sure you've changed the code. Just tell us what error are you getting now?

Comment: very similar to this pastebin.com/ZPTuiaZQ

Comment: I think we need the exact version

Comment: ~Stack() is not defined, but used in stack.c, line 65

Comment: Stack.C:62:5: error: no match for ‘operator~’ (operand type is ‘Stack<int>’)
     ~Stack();

Comment: OMG i found it it... Thank you

Comment: so what it was finally?

Comment: it was not defined? lack of { } ?